# How to use KWin compositor without hardware acceleration

Tags: xorg, hardware-acceleration, kwin, compositing

I use GPU without hardware acceleration (`nouveau.noaccel=1`). I am using KDE Plasma with kwin_x11. I know, that KWin has it own compositor. There is transparency, but no animations. So can I get animations with disabled hardware acceleration?

Graphics info:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] driver: nouveau v: kernel arch: Tesla
    pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: DVI-I-1 empty: DVI-I-2
    bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:0402 temp: 49.0 C
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9
    compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: swrast gpu: nouveau display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: DVI-I-1 model: ViewSonic VX2770 SERIES res: 1920x1080 dpi: 82
    diag: 685mm (27")
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits)
    direct-render: Yes
```